# Postgresql Locking Rows For Update with Temporary Table

Tags: postgresql

I am having problems with the following function. The purpose of this function is to return a set of records that will not be returned again if called within 60 seconds (Almost like a queue).

It seems to work fine when I run this one a time, however when I am using it in my threaded application, I see duplicates that show up. Am I locking the rows correctly? What is the correct way to use FOR UPDATE when inserting into a temp table?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION needs_quantities(computer TEXT)
  RETURNS TABLE(id BIGINT, listing_id CHARACTER VARYING, asin CHARACTER VARYING, retry_count INT)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$

BEGIN


  CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_needs_quantity ON COMMIT DROP
  AS

    SELECT
      listing.id,
      listing.listing_id,
      listing.asin,
      listing.retry_count
    FROM listing
    WHERE listing.id IN (
      SELECT min(listing.id) AS id
      FROM listing
      WHERE (listing.quantity_assigned_to IS NULL

             --quantity is null
             -- and quantity assigned date is at least 60 seconds ago
             -- and quantity date is within 2 hours

             OR (
               quantity IS NULL AND listing.quantity_assigned_date < now_utc() - INTERVAL '60 second'
               AND (listing.quantity_date IS NULL OR listing.quantity_date > now_utc() - INTERVAL '2 hour')
             )

            )
            AND listing.retry_count < 10


      GROUP BY listing.asin
      ORDER BY min(listing.retry_count), min(listing_date)
      LIMIT 10

    )
    FOR UPDATE;


  UPDATE listing
  SET quantity_assigned_date = now_utc(), quantity_assigned_to = computer
  WHERE listing.id IN (SELECT temp_needs_quantity.id
                       FROM temp_needs_quantity);

  RETURN QUERY
  SELECT *
  FROM temp_needs_quantity
  ORDER BY id;


END
$$
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function should lock the rows in `listing` like you intended in the first thread that comes along.

The problem in the second thread is that this subselect:

```
...
WHERE listing.id IN (
  SELECT min(listing.id) AS id
  FROM listing
  ...
  LIMIT 10
)
```

is *not* blocked by the lock on the rows, even though the enclosing `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` is.

So the subselect will happily see the old row versions from *before* the `UPDATE` of the first thread, then blocks in the enclosing `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` until the first thread is done. Then it proceeds to update the same rows again.

I am not sure if that is to be considered a bug or not – you may want to ask at the pgsql-general mailing list.
There has been a similar problem with CTEs recently, see [this commit message](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commitdiff;h=73df86a37ba54e35ba8d9e09bc9fe5699b196829) fixing [this bug](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20160919160136.1348.55251@wrigleys.postgresql.org). One could argue that this is a similar case.

Unfortunately with a complicated query like yours I can't think of a better solution than to

```
LOCK TABLE listing IN EXCLUSIVE MODE;
```

before you begin processing, which is not very satisfactory.